# MySQL select count from different columns using also group by

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

[image]

I have this table called tasks. I want to fetch count of the total task of each assign_date and on that date how many complete task by complete_date per user.

I want something like below

```
    [{
      user_id:1 ,
      assign_date / compete_date : 2019-09-04,
     assign_task : 2,
    complete_task: 1
    },
{
      user_id:1 ,
      assign_date / compete_date : 2019-09-19,
     assign_task : 1,
    complete_task: 2
    }
]
```

Comment: and what query you have tried so far?

Comment: select count(*) as assign, assign_date, user_id  from `tasks` 
where Month(assign_date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) and user_id=1   GROUP BY assign_date ORDER BY assign_date

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your query. using `union all` will get the count on both assigned and complete dates

```
select user_id
    , complete_date as [assign_date / compete_date]
    , sum(case when t1.s = 'assigned' then 1 else 0 end) as assign_task
    , sum(case when t1.s = 'complete' then 1 else 0 end) as complete_task
from
    (select user_Id, complete_date, 'complete' as s from task 
    union all
    select user_Id, assign_date, 'assigned' as s from task) t1
group by t1.complete_date, t1.user_id
```

Comment: Not getting the correct result. For 2019-09-04 we are getting assign : 1 , complete : 1 for user_id: 1. But if you see data assign should be 2

Comment: I changed the grouping, please try again

Comment: it's changed but i can see it's opposite. means  complete : 2 , assign 1. It will be sssign : 2, complete 1

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select user_id,date, count(assign_date) assign_task,count(compete_date) complete_task
from tablename
group by user_id,date
```